# Why don't my views show up in Storyboards and are greyed out in the left pane?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

[image]

I am experiencing a weird bug in Storyboards.

I set up a `UITableViewController` with *prototype cells* and set some autolayout constraints. Everything fine until here.

Then, I had to move the whole project directory into another folder. This is a normal action I believe that shouldn't lead to any problems since the app and all the files are pretty much self-contained.

However, since I moved the project, the *prototype cells* in the `UITableView` are shown empty within my Storyboard, but the subviews are still showing up in the left pane where all the scenes and views are shown... Only that they are greyed out (see the screenshot)... Does anyone know what this means? I also looked into the XML of the  Storyboard file, but everything seemed normal to me in there...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Strange thing also is that the `IBOutlets` from the custom classes still are set and link to the views in the storyboard... but only in the left pane, not in the storyboard itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found an answer myself, it was because **Size Classes were reset** after I moved the project...

**Greying out views is Xcode's standard behaviour when the views are only set for a specific size class which is currently not selected!**

I had set the size classes for my `UIViewController` to `Compact - Any`, this is what it looks like in proper state:

[image]

The problem occurs when I change the size classes to another one (e.g. `Any - Any`):

[image]

Comment: It's a new feature that Apple released with iOS 8 and Xcode 6, it helps to deal with the different screen sizes of the existing iPhones. There are _three_ of them: **Compact**, **Regular** and **Any**. You can read more about size classes here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Comment: good, I added some screenshots to my answer to help prevent any future confusion ;)

Comment: @nburk How and where did you change the size class?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I copy and pasted some of my views from nib into storybaord. Turning size classes off, and turning it back on fixed the issue. This can be done in `File inspector`, using a checkbox named `Use Size Classes`