# Interface Builder Objects not visible in my storyboard (and titles are transparent)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I am using the same version of XCode as another developer I am working with but when I open the project on my machine the interface objects are not visible in the storyboard and their names are semi-transparent. I’ve Googled around but I cannot seem to figure out why this might be happening.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

[image: Interface Builder transparent objects]

Comment: Are you able to compile everything without errors?

Comment: @NewEngland Yep! The app builds and runs just fine.

Comment: Odd. A friend of mine was experiencing this too

Comment: At the risk of sounding nooby, have you un/reinstalled? Also, those playground files look scary. Is this also happening when you create a brand new project?

Comment: Hi @NewEngland, please don’t worry about offending me :) I’m relatively new to Storyboards as I usually lay out my interfaces in code. When you say reinstall, do you mean XCode? I’ve tried downloading the latest stable version and beta version but that hasn't solved it. Fresh projects seem to be working just fine so I think it must be some setting or difference in our two development environments. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the views have been set for a different *size class* in Interface Builder, and not `Any & Any`, which you have currently selected.

Just change the size class in the interface builder appropriately and the views will be back! :)

I encountered the same issue, read more here: [Why don't my views show up in Storyboards and are greyed out in the left pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111390/why-dont-my-views-show-up-in-storyboards-and-are-greyed-out-in-the-left-pane/27111499#27111499)

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you!