# How do I bring from the dead elements from a viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I have this viewController I copied from a storyboard using Size Classes to another one that is not using Size Classes.

Before you say anything: there is a bug on XCode/iOS or whatever, that prevents a SplitViewController from being the rootViewController on iPads running iOS 7, unless you turn off size classes on xcode.

I have copied this viewController to the storyboard not using Size Classes and now all elements are grayed out.

[image]

How do I bring that to life?

It is not easy as you think.

Comment: Turn off size classes _first_ in the original storyboard, and _then_ copy?

Comment: Alternatively, edit the storyboard file in vim.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - and what should I change there?

Comment: @matt - please make your comment an answer. It is correct and the only way to do this. THANKS!

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper Did so - delighted to hear this worked, as it was just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but what I would try is: Turn off size classes first in the original storyboard, and then copy.

(If you don't want to risk losing information from the original when you turn off size classes, make a duplicate of the original storyboard first.)

Comment: yes, this is what I did. By turning off size classes it craps the whole storyboard but the viewController can be copied fine. This is why it is important to make a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, my answer was just a guess. You've found a very interesting problem for people trying to make backwards-compatible apps; I hope you submit it in a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I did. I have about 60 Xcode bugs filled... some for 3 years without a solution. [This will be the next one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924968/getting-the-color-of-a-viewcontrollers-navigationbar). 

Answer (score 0):

It's because the **views have been set for a different size class in Interface Builder** than the one which you have currently selected.

I encountered the same issue, read more here: [Why don't my views show up in Storyboards and are greyed out in the left pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111390/why-dont-my-views-show-up-in-storyboards-and-are-greyed-out-in-the-left-pane/27111499#27111499) and [Interface Builder Objects not visible in my storyboard (and titles are transparent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437063/interface-builder-objects-not-visible-in-my-storyboard-and-titles-are-transpare/27447064#27447064)

Comment: Thanks but this solution would work if I had copied the elements from a storyboard without size classes to another with with size classes but because I did the inverse, I don't have the option any/any at the bottom. So, your solution won't work.