# UI elements not visible on Storyboard editor, but visible on some device sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I hope this isn't a duplicate, I just couldn't find a similar issue.

I am using Storyboards and autolayout. After making additional changes to the UI, in a particular view all of the UI elements are not visible in the storyboard editor, but they do show up on an iPhone 5 and 6. Unfortunately (probably due to the storyboard issue) the UI elements do not show up on an iPad.

Here are some images to hopefully help understand this:

[image]
This is the storyboard view. Notice how the UI elements on the left are grayed out, while their coordinates are within the expected viewing area. Also, no constrains have been added to these UI elements.

Here's how the UI looks like at runtime on iPhone 6:
[image]

And here's again the blank UI on iPad air:
[image]

I truly have no clue what's going on with this particular view, so any suggestions, guidance or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: does my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, sorry SO didn't let me mark it as answered before, but I will now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the **views have been set for a different size class in Interface Builder** than the one which you have currently selected.

Just modify your current size class to the one for which the views have been defined.

I encountered the same issue, read more here: [Why don't my views show up in Storyboards and are greyed out in the left pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111390/why-dont-my-views-show-up-in-storyboards-and-are-greyed-out-in-the-left-pane/27111499#27111499) and [Interface Builder Objects not visible in my storyboard (and titles are transparent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437063/interface-builder-objects-not-visible-in-my-storyboard-and-titles-are-transpare/27447064#27447064)

Note that whenever you have a particular size class selected, all UI elements will only be available/visible within that particular size class.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to figure this part out. How to make the UI elements that are visible in the "compact" view then appear also in the "Any" view? I can move them around in the "compact" view but they still don't show up/become visible in the "any" view

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, you just need to switch from specific viewing as device to another and they will appear again ... For example: if you're viewing as iPhone8+ then switch to iPad and then switch it back to iPhone and it'll work.