# Size Class Issues - Also need a size class key

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

In Xcode I am having an issue with the size classes in my app.  I am unable to get the right size classes to show that seem to work for all of my different devices.  I kind of would like a key to see what the size classes should really be, also the size classes don't seem to really match up.

Below is an image attached of an example.  I can't get anything correct.  I am new to this and I know that I am doing something wrong.

Also, I tried this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html but it didn't match up.  Maybe my controls have a layout issue?

[image: Size Layout and Size Classes]

Edit: Shown below, I can't modify the leading edges and trailing edges...

[image]

Comment: if you're _completely_ new to this, it's always a good idea to start out with a tutorial before moving on to own projects :) I can recommend Ray Wenderlich's take on size classes: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: @nburk, I sware I tried all of that.

Comment: from the image, it seems like you need to set `trailing space` and `leading space` on your UI elements to fit them to the superview's width

Comment: I can't add them either, that option is greyed out on my uiwebview

Comment: if a view is greyed out, it means that is has been set on a different size class than the one being currently selected, check my old question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111390/why-dont-my-views-show-up-in-storyboards-and-are-greyed-out-in-the-left-pane

Comment: The view its self is not greed out, its the "Leading Edges," and "Trailing Edges"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoo Hooo!!!  I figured it out!!!  @nburk, I want to give you some credit too.  You said the key words trailing space and leading space so I googled more on that, and I was seeing the wrong thing.

I want to recommend this to all users who are having problems with it.  I didn't realize that dragging the constraints using the control button would actually do it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

Bill.